# can't get computed to work in a super simple html & js script

Tags: vue.js

Just started on a vue tutorial and am simple stuck within the first 5 minutes trying to follow their example - these are my 2 files ( i try to start without building a vue project but include it directly in the html ).

the on Input works but the part with myFunc isn't working ( it should work according the tutorial but not in my end ) - the result i get on screen is this :

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcroz.png)

The code here - very simple - anyone can help what it is i'm doing wrong ?

index.html

```
<head><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
 <script src="jsTest.js"></script>
<div id ="app">
    <h3>hello</h3>
    <div>input:
      <input v-on:input="onInput"/>
    </div> 
    output:
    {{ myFunc }}
    <div v-html ="myFunc" />
</div> 
</div>  
</div>
</body>
```

jstest.js

```
console.log ("wew");
new Vue({
    el :"#app",
     data: {
         textInput :''
     },
     computed: {
        myFunc : function () {
            this.textInput = "*";
        }
     },
      methods : {
        onInput : function (event) {
          this.textInput = event.target.value;
        }
    }
  });
```

Comment: you're trying to assign a value to textInput in the computed property. use it to "compute" something not to assign.

Comment: could you show me by correcting the code to something that computes instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many errors.

- `data` should return an object
- The `computed` should be use to display a (formatted) value

Here is you code corrected :

Working codepen : https://codepen.io/Andugal/pen/yLYOmMq?editors=1111

```
new Vue({
     el :"#app",
     data () {
       return {
         textInput :''
       }
     },
     computed: {
        myFunc : function () {
          return this.textInput
        }
     },
     methods : {
       onInput : function (event) {
         this.textInput = event.target.value;
       }
     }
  });
```

Comment: thanks alot - i am totally newbie in fronted here sorry. But your example works perfectly in codepen - but when it make index.html with your content + jstest.js with your content in VS code and try to host it - it still shows {{ myFunc }} as output in the browser ?  what i am doing wrong when it works perfect in codepen :(

Comment: no error messages at all :- my visual studio + outout here  https://imgur.com/a/PsfEXB3

Comment: @ssai I didn't see `<script src="jsTest.js"></script>` Maybe you forgot to add it ?